# Shader to combine two sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, sprite

I have *two* sprites that I need to combine into *one*. I have a shader using **Shaderlab** syntax which works well for normal textures, but SpireRenderer gives warnings about it being a *Fixed function shader* plus it does not work with the `Sprite Packer`.

This is my goal:
[image]

So there is a *base sprite* which is used for the background and the *image sprite* which gives the card its final look. With ShaderLab I could just use "Combine Texture" to do this, but I have no idea how or if it is possible to do with CG.

Comment: When does this process happen ? Can it be done on initialization or does it need to happen on the framebuffer ?

Comment: @user1610743 Yes it should be done on the framebuffer. Doing texture combining in the initialization cranks the up the load time too much.

Comment: Thing is, doing something 1x during initialization is far superior to doing something over and over with each frame. This is especially true if you need to do the combination multiple times within each frame. I can't post some code for you, as I'm not sure why it would be bad to render the combination one time into a framebuffer, copy that to a texture buffer (intra GPU) and later use that texture as the pre-processed combination. Also, i'm not familiar with Unity3D that much. It would really save u some performance for ur later game-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The blending could work something like this:

```c
fixed4 bg = tex2D(_BackgroundSprite, IN.uv);
fixed4 fg = tex2D(_ForegroundSprite, IN.uv);

fixed3 col = fixed3(fg.rgb * fg.a + bg.rgb * bg.a * (1 - fg.a));
return fixed4(col, fg.a + fg.b * (1 - fg.a));
```